# Emit an event dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-decorator

I am trying to create a child component where I want to emit an event to the parent based on some condition.

For simplicity's sake, let's say that I have a child component and will take an input(boolean), and based on that input I want to, later on, emit an event.

```
<child-component
  [canEmitValue]="false"
  (emitValue)="someMethod()" //I want to add this emitValue based on the input.
>
</child-component>
```

We're trying to create a reusable component and we want to hide the the event based on something.

Questions:

- Is there a way to add the event dynamically i.e add the behaviour of @Output without implicitly specifying the @Output
- If not, is there any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom event based on something I found out that you can:

```
constructor(
    private el:ElementRef
  ) {  }


 ... some code

 public someMethodThatChecksSoething(){

   this.el.nativeElement
        .dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('todo', {
          detail: value,
          bubbles: true
        }));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to add the event dynamically i.e add the behaviour of @Output without implicitly specifying the @Output

No that's not the concept of input/output binding in Angular. Read more here:
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

In the parent template the event binding `(emitValue)="someMethod($event)"` connects the event in the child to the parent.

What I understand you're basically trying to 'disable' the component. In that case; the output event emitter inside the child component should check the input value and not emit anything to the parent.

Alternatively you can try, which I do not recommend:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>
    Content to render when condition is true.
    <child-component [canEmitValue]="condition" (emitValue)="someMethod()"></child-component>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    Content to render when condition is false.
    <child-component [canEmitValue]="condition" ></child-component>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Yes, u understand correctly. But i want also to somehow remove the event emitter if some other dev is trying to use my component. 
So yes I can disable based on the input but, I was thinking if maybe there is a way to also remove that i.e (emitValue) not to be shown at all.